# Can't detect that string is "c++ comment"

Tags: regex, tcl

I try to find a comment in a `c++` code file with tcl, but I'm having trouble with `regexp`

```
set str "\\ads dsa dsad s  s s s "
set result [regexp { ^\\\\ } $str]
puts "result = $result"
```

It prints : `result = 0`, but I can't understand why.

Comment: Note that ``^\\\\`` searches for 2 backslashes at the start of the string, but you only have 1. `set result [regexp {^\\} $str]` will yield `result = 1`. Did you mean to test the regex against `set str {\\ads dsa dsad s  s s s}`? See https://ideone.com/sVOxNE

Comment: Is a C++ comment not `//` --  Strange that you are using backslashes for commenting?  If that's the case .. Your regex *should* be `^\/\/.*` IE [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/1errTK/1)

Comment: @Zak: There is no need to escape forward slashes as they have no special meaning in regular expressions. Also `.*` serves no function in this case. So, the regex could simply be `^//`

Comment: Sometimes it is better to use a different RE, if just for readability: `^[\\]{2}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String in curved brackets is fixed. You are trying to find a match for the "`(space)^\\\\(space)`". I believe that you want to use something like this:

```
set result [regexp {^\s*\\\\} $str]
```

Also, you have bad sample string. Backslashes will be combined because of doublequotes.
I believe that you want to use something like this:

```
set str "\\\\ads dsa dsad s  s s s "
```

or

```
set str {\\ads dsa dsad s  s s s }
```